# Creating VBA If Then Loop through Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have two bits of codes that work seperatley,  but I can't figure out how to combine them. I want to go through a column of numbers and test if they are >= 100 and then change the result if true.

I don't know how many rows this column will be so I have used the following line in another part of this Macro.

```
Range("D1:D" & Final & "").
```

And I have successfully tested a single cell by directly specifiying it like so:

```
Sub CellTest()
Dim cell As Integer
cell = Range("D7").Value
If cell >= 100 Then
Range("D7").Value = "NoSplit"
End If
End Sub
```

Can anybody help me combine these so it iterates through every row and tests the value?

Update:

This spreadsheet is downloaded via a script on a webpage and has a different name each time. There are a few things I will know ahead of time such as...

- There is only 1 sheet
- The column in question is column D
- column D will only  have numbers with no decimal points
- I will not know how many rows in this column ahead of time

Comment: I see that there's an answer for you listed, but will bring up some basics for looping.  A loop will iterate through an array of values; that's it.  What you do with that can be simple or complex.  Let's use "i" as a variable to account for iterating... your data can be a range of cells in column A (1)  from rows 1 to 10 and you want to go 1 by 1, e.g., 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, etc.  You can generate a for loop to account for this, such that *For i = 1 to 10 Step 1*, then you can utilize the iterated value (rows) using *cells(i,1).value = ""* inside of your loop.

Comment: @Cyril I saw the demo of that method, but was unsure how to utilize it since I don't know how many rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub testforhundred()
    Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Value >= 100 Then rcell.Value = "NoSplit"
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

this combines them easily. However if the row count is huge itll be time consuming due to interacting with the sheet object

Comment: Hmm the sheet name will change per use, so having it hard coded is a no go :(

Comment: Will it be a specified sheet or the `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, your question doesn't mention anything about dynamic sheets. If this is a criteria, it needs to be listed in your question. Even with your comment, it's not clear what sheet. Do you want to loop this code through all sheets? Some sheet? Will it just run on the selected sheet? Please [edit] your question and specify any criteria

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers For all extensive purposes, an answer can explain how to do something (which doesn't have to be a copy-pasteable response), where it is an understood assumption that persons asking questions have some understanding of the subject matter when conversing with *experts*.  Essentially, the poster of a question must be able to recognize the point made by the expert answering said question.

Comment: With [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet), you should be able to apply Doug's answer to your code. (Don't forget to mark it as correct if it solves your issue).

Comment: wow, ok so a lot has happened since i was here last @FreeSoftwareServers if you can provide information to sheet naming conventions I can assist with something that will work for you. Or if the if active worksheet works for you, whatever. however it is considered bad practice to reference active.whatever.

Comment: @DougCoats after further reading your code, I still havn't tested as I'm busy on the floor, I'm curious how it knows which column? Your code looks like it would apply to entire worksheet, I can't have that, it only needs to test Column D.

Comment: @FreesoftwareServers Sorry my mistake, I have fixed this for you. I made sure to test it this time.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers my statement was a bit vague.  as is written in Doug's response, the requested information is present, where it is shown how to loop through the cells.  depending on how it was tested/utilized by the person coding, some sheet names may differ from the original post, or it may be that some qualifications are not exact, though the key-concept remains.  regarding the statement from /u/urdearboy in response to your statement that a hard-coded sheet is a "no go", that is A) out of scope for the question, and B) considered something that can be modified by the Question Poster.